# Site Stats link points to nothing

Tags: bug, status-completed, broken-link

In the right pane, there is a box contain **Site Stats** and in it, a link called **Stack Exchange** under the title **More site stats**.

The link points to a url https://stackexchange.com/?expand=true#politics,

Which take us to nothing other than the SE home page.

Comment: You should ask about this on meta.stachexchange.com

Comment: @SamIam I believe the Stack Exchange devs keep track of all meta questions tagged as [meta-tag:bug], [meta-tag:feature-request], etc on all sites. It *shouldn't* matter where you ask it.

Comment: @SamIam - no need to post that on MSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of the work to move all sites to HTTPS, a lot of links got changed, this one got an incorrect change.

Fixed in the next release (after rev 2017.3.16.25440)